# jQuery send post request with php variable?

Tags: php, jquery

hello friends This is my code.

```
$.post("submit_investorform.php",{'flage':'firstOverviewsubmit','comname':comaname,'amoutwisr':amoutwisr,'user_id':<?php echo $value = isset($_GET['user_id']) ?  $_GET['user_id'] : ""; ?>},function(result){
    if(result.trim() == 'Insert'){
        $(".noterror").html("Record Insert Successfully");
        $(".noterror").show();
        return false;
    }else if(result.trim() == 'error'){
        $(".errordisplay").html("Something was Wrong Please Try Again");
        $(".errordisplay").show();
        return false;
    }else if(result.trim() == "update"){
        $(".noterror").html("Record Updated Successfully");
        $(".noterror").show();
        return false;
    }

});
```

i want to do the user_id is set then is send into post request otherwise it send blank.
but jQuery return syntax error.

please help.

Comment: what is the exact syntax error you are getting?
Also is amoutwisr and comaname been defined somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
'user_id': '<?php echo $value = isset($_GET['user_id']) ?  $_GET['user_id'] : ""; ?>'
```

You need to wrap your `PHP` code within quotes to avoid syntax error, if the `$_GET['user_id']` is not set.